# How to convert XML to AVRO based on the Avro Schema?

Tags: java, xml, avro, apache-kafka-connect, xml-to-json

I have a `structured XML` data. I want to convert this `XML to AVRO(or JSON)` using `AVRO schema`. I've defined the AVRO schema for this XML. But how can I convert it in java?

Actually, I want to convert received xml data from the server to the JSON/AVRO format in the `Kafka Connect`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Kafka Connect, you can use the [XML Single Message Transform](https://www.confluent.io/connector/xml-transformation/) to do exactly this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I've looked this transform. But my received xml may be have different structure. I'm using a global xml standart, and this standart have different versions such as 1.2, 1.3 etc. Each of them has different XSD schema. I want to convert xml to json based on the avro schema rather than the using xsd. For this, I'll define a global AVRO schema. For example, Apache Nifi, converts XML to JSON or AVRO using AVRO schema. In this case, I can define a global XSD schema, and use this transform. But, XSD schema is very complicated for me. Which options is better?